Mpesa STK Push, I am having problems with customizing stk push message
I want to customize the stk push info that gets to client side, And I understand that transactiondesc is limited to 13 characters and accountreference 12 characters, how do I achieve to have something like this?
"Dear customer, you are about to pay {$amount} Kshs to Lipagas Limited. Enter your M-PESA PIN to complete the transaction."
Tried to change to  'TransactionDesc' => 'Do you want to pay ' . $amount . ' to Lipagas Limited. Enter PIN',
but it still did not work.
